# Using rotation matrix for spin to write x oriented spin in z-spin basis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, hilbert-space

$\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right>}$The problem is to write the ket vector for a particle with
spin +1/2 along the x axis, in terms of the standard basis
vectors $\ket{+1/2}$ and $\ket{-1/2}$ along the z axis.

[This page](https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node279.html)
gives the rotation matrix about y axis as:

\begin{pmatrix}
 \cos (\theta/2) &  \sin(\theta/2)\\
-\sin (\theta/2) &  \cos(\theta/2)
\end{pmatrix}
So I figure if I just rotate the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}  1 \\0\end{smallmatrix} \right) $  90 degrees
around the y axis, that will produce the answer.  (Since
a z oriented vector rotated 90 degrees about the y axis
produces an x oriented vector).

But multiplying the above matrix by the vector $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}  1 \\0\end{smallmatrix} \right) $ gives $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}  \cos(90^\circ/2) \\-\sin(90^\circ/2) \end{smallmatrix} \right) $

which is $$\begin{pmatrix}  \cos(45^\circ) \\ -\sin(45^\circ)\end{pmatrix}  
= \begin{pmatrix} 1/\sqrt2 \\ -1/\sqrt2\end{pmatrix} $$.

But the book says the answer is $\hbar/2 \cdot \ket{-1/2}$
which I believe is the same as $\hbar/2 \cdot \left(\begin{smallmatrix}  0 \\1\end{smallmatrix} \right) $ .
What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that's what the book is asking you to find?

$\hbar/2$ is the eigenvalue of the $S_{x}$ operator corresponding to spin up, but it is not part of the state vector. If the question is really asking you to express the $\mid S_{x};+\rangle$ ket in the $S_{z}$ basis, then you're nearly correct, just a minor sign error:

$$\mid S_{x};+\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mid+\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\mid-\rangle$$

Comment: I think you're right that I misread the question.  Here is their solution:

Comment: $\hat{S_x}|(+1/2)\rangle = \hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} = \hbar/2|(-1/2)\rangle$

Comment: I assume that your $|+\rangle$ notation means, to them, $|(+1/2)\rangle$.  Still trying to understand your answer.  Thank you for giving it.

Comment: Yes, that's right. $\mid \pm \rangle$ = $\mid (\pm1/2) \rangle$. 

$\hat S_{x}\mid (+1/2) \rangle$ corresponds to measuring the spin along the $x$-axis when the particle's spin is oriented along the positive $z$-axis.

First they express the $\hat S_{x}$ operator in the ($\mid (\pm1/2) \rangle$) basis

$$\hat S_{x} = \hbar/2 \mid (+1/2) \rangle \langle (-1/2) \mid + \hbar/2 \mid (-1/2) \rangle \langle (+1/2) = \hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

where they use the matrix representation of the operator. Then they apply the operator to the state vector $\mid (+1/2) \rangle$.

Comment: Note that this equivalent to

$$\hat S_{x}\mid (+1/2) \rangle = \hbar/2 \mid (+1/2) \rangle \langle (-1/2) \mid (+1/2) \rangle  + \hbar/2 \mid (-1/2) \rangle \langle (+1/2) \mid (+1/2) \rangle $$

Since the $\mid (\pm1/2) \rangle$ vectors are orthonormal, $\langle (-1/2) \mid (+1/2) \rangle = 0$ and $\langle (+1/2) \mid (+1/2) \rangle = 1$, giving

$$\hat S_{x}\mid (+1/2) \rangle = \hbar/2 \mid (-1/2) \rangle$$

I still don't know what the problem statement is, but hopefully this provides some clarity. You might find it useful to read about the Pauli matrices.

Comment: The full problem statement is:  Using the basis vectors of $\hat{S_z}$ eigenvectors, calculate $\hat{S_i} |(+1/2)\rangle$ and $\hat{S_i} |(-1/2)\rangle$  (i = x,y,z), where $|(+1/2)\rangle$ and $|(-1/2)\rangle$ are the eigenvectors of $\hat{S_z}$ with eigenvalues $\hbar/2$ and $-\hbar/2$, respectively.

Comment: In your first comment, I see that ℏ/2 * |(+1/2)⟩⟨(−1/2)| + ℏ/2 * |(−1/2)⟩⟨(+1/2)| = ℏ/2 $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ because ℏ/2 * $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ (0 1) + ℏ/2 * $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ (1 0) = ℏ/2 * $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ + ℏ/2 * $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.  Thank you.

Comment: Moving my previous comments over to the question:

Comment: Again, the solution your book provides is not the answer to the question you're asking. The book solution corresponds to "the outcome of a measurement along the x-axis of a particle that is spin up in the z basis." This is not the same as what you're asking, which is to write the expansion of spin up along the x-axis in the z basis, which is the result I've given. Your approach is entirely correct, you just made a sign error in the second coefficient.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Okay, the problem statement seems pretty clear. No need to expand the kets into different bases. You can just multiply the ket in the $z$ basis by each of the Pauli matrices, which are the spin operator matrices in the $z$ basis. Hope that clears things up :)

Comment: again regarding your first comment:  Now I understand what you are saying.  You're saying I could  "derive"  the $\hat{S_x}$  operator via that ket-bra construction.  And your second comment performs the same calculation  (to solve the problem)  a different way

Comment: I also understand now your third comment, how my question differs from the book problem.  Great.  Thank you.

Comment: Yes, correct. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I think you could work it like this:

$X_+ ={1 \over \sqrt{2}} (\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}) =a (\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix} ) +b(\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{matrix} )  $.where $X_+$ is the eigenvector on the positive axon of $S_x$

Solve and find a,b and there you are.

Note also that you can write a general spinor as $(\begin{matrix} cos\theta /2 \\ sin\theta /2 \cdot e^{ι \phi} \end{matrix} ) $ where $\theta$ is the angle in zy plane starting from z and $\phi$ is the angle at xy plane starting from x.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where does $X_+ = 1/\sqrt 2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ come from, please?

Comment: Hi. If I'm not mistaken that's the eigenvector of the operator $S_x $ on the positive x axon. On the the other side there is the vector at z axon. Here, have a look: http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node267.html If I understood your question well, you want to express the spinor on x on the z basis. That's what my answer is showing, but you have to calculate the coefficients a and b.

Comment: Again, the solution your book provides is not the answer to the question you're asking. The book solution corresponds to "the outcome of a measurement along the $x$-axis of a particle that is spin up in the $z$ basis." This is not the same as what you're asking, which is to write the expansion of spin up along the $x$-axis in the $z$ basis, which is the result I've given. Your approach is entirely correct, you just made a sign error in the second coefficient.

Comment: Another approach: In general, if you you know the form of an operator A in a basis b, where the b's are eigenvectors some operator B and A and B don't commute, you can solve the eigenvalue problem $A a = \lambda a$ to find the a's in terms of the b's. In this problem you know the representation of $S_{x}$ in the $z$ basis - it's just the Pauli matrix $\sigma_{x}$. Solving the eigenvalue problem will give the eigenvectors of $S_{x}$ in the $z$ basis, and then it's a matter of finding the coefficients a and b as in Constantine's answer. This is done by requiring that $|a|^{2} + |b|^{2} = 1$

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines   ,Hello. I'm sorry, but are the comments for me(Constantine Black) or for the poster of the question? Thanks.

Comment: Ah, I apologize. I'll move them over to the question

Comment: @KyleArean-Raines    ,No problem. It happens even to the best :) .

Comment: Constantine B.:  I think what you're saying is that the z vectors $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ constitute a basis, so that when we seek the |X+> vector, we know it can be expressed in the form a*|Z+> + b*|Z->.  THEN, we know that the |X+> vector is an eigenvector of the $\hat{S_x}$ matrix, so we can write the eigenvalue equation $\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ * |X+> = $\lambda$ * |X+>, and then solve.  I appreciate your explaining this approach.

Comment: @user4127427    If you have time, you could have a look at the site I commented above. There you will see exactly how you find the eigenvectors of a spin operator-as you said. From there you do what my answer says and you have your solution. Note that there other exercises were you will have to find the the x spinor as a superposition of the y spinor and so on. Happy I helped.

Comment: @Constantine B.:  To finish up:   that UCSD page worked for me.  (I still do not understand what you said about the spinor, but I haven't learned about those yet.)  Ultimately, the starting point I come up with is   $\hbar/2 \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}[a*|(+1/2)\rangle + b|(-1/2)\rangle] = \hbar/2 * [a*|(+1/2)\rangle + b*|(-1/2)\rangle]$

Comment: @Constantine B.:  Replacing $|(+1/2)\rangle$ with $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $|(-1/2)\rangle$ with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and doing the calculation, you end up with two equations, b=a and a=b.  Thus the solution is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and normalize.  Thank you for helping me through this approach.

Comment: @Kyle Arean-Raines:   I think your final comment is pointing out that one use of operators is as a  "basis converter,"  if you already have the matrix that is the expression of the operator in the basis you want to get to.  (as is the case in Pauli x matrix represents x spin and the $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ expression is for the z spin standard basis).  If this is not correct, that's okay;  I'm sure I'll get the hang of it sooner or later.

Comment: Not quite. When you apply an operator to a ket, you can either express the operator in the ket basis or express the ket in the operator basis (expand the ket in terms of the eigenkets of the operator). Keep at it, these concepts can take a while to sink in :)